# Extending OutputStream class; write(int) method

Tags: java, outputstream

So my goal is to implement the write method in the class OutputStream to create a new class NumStream, which basically converts ints to Strings. Here is my sample code:

```
import java.io.*; 
public class NumStream extends OutputStream {
    public void write(int c) throws IOException {
        // What goes here?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumStream ns = new NumStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ns));
        pw.println("123456789 and ! and # ");
        pw.flush(); // needed for anything to happen, try taking it out
    }
}
```

I've tried using several different approaches, and my result always results in the program compiling, but when I run it, nothing happens. So far I've tried using switch statements to produce this result:

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException {
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    switch (c) {
        case 1: sb.append("1");
        break;
    //etc. through 9
```

I'm unsure of what to do or try next to produce a result. :/ Any tips to steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Integer.toString(c)? But I think what you're trying to do might be a bad idea...

Comment: [Integer.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int))

Comment: I tried using Integer.toString() but I still got nothing when I ran the program. :/

Comment: Where are the results of the StringBuffer going?  I guess it should be a StringBuilder as the Javadoc says.

Comment: [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) already does this with its `print(int)` method.  Any reason you can't use this instead of writing your own `NumStream` class?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too, Here is the solution:

```
public class MyOutputStream extends OutputStream {

 StringBuilder anotatedText;

 public MyOutputStream() {
  // Custom constructor
 }

 @Override
 public void write(int b) {
     int[] bytes = {b};
     write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
 }

 public void write(int[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
     String s = new String(bytes, offset, length);
     anotatedText.append(s);
 }

 public void myPrint() {
     System.out.println(anotatedText);
 }
}
```

All we need to do is to implement the "write" method correctly which is clearly instructed in the above example.